listening to calls in the background with flutter and retrieving information from firebase
In an application I wrote with Flutter, I need to build a structure that will display an alert screen by taking customer information from firebase according to the number when a call comes in. My customer especially wants this so that he can address his customers by name. I would be very grateful if you help me. Thank you very much in advance.
I can listen to calls with flutter_foreground_task but I don't get a notification when the app is closed.
